# Changing The Size of Twitter's Follow Button?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm looking at the new Twitter Follow Button (https://twitter.com/about/resources/followbutton), but unfortunately my sidebar is smaller than the default size, thus throwing my whole site out of whack.

Is there an easy way to hack the script to resize the button, or at least to put a line break between the actual follow button and the account name?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the page source, then your twitter code converts from

```
<div class="twitter">
  <!-- twitter code here -->
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="twitter">
  <iframe ...>...</iframe>
</div>
```

Now it's easy to change the width of the button via css:

```
.twitter iframe {
  width: 80px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd wrap the button in a container with a nice class name and use CSS to adjust the styling.

```
.twitter-button-container{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Something like that.

**UPDATE**

On second thought, it seems that the image is a background image to the anchor tag. I don't think it's possible to resize background images using CSS etc. You'd need to have the image in an `img` tag.